# Stop single quartz scheduler

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I have 5 different quartz schedulers which implement 5 different jobs. If I am stopping one scheduler, remaining schedulers are getting stopped. Why?

Comment: You should add more detail in your question, like actual relevant code and configuration snippets, to make it more clear and get some answers.

Comment: Why different schedulers, one for each job? why not just one? Also, need more details as mentioned by guido.

Comment: You are either confusing *scheduler* with *trigger* or if not - you should use different *triggers*, not *schedulers* :-). You can add/remove triggers at runtime on one scheduler.

Comment: hi @Vikdor above i have attached the files..

Comment: hi @TomaszNurkiewicz , below are the files im working on..two are quartz shedulers and invoking them from main method of other class. http://pastebin.com/j8KrHgD3
http://pastebin.com/Ekf83Tzj
http://pastebin.com/AJ4FtqTz

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure your actually creating references to the same Scheduler, you need to give each scheduler a different "SchedulerName". At the moment it looks like each time your creating a new scheduler its defaulting the SchedulerName.

> The "job executor" is actually not the SchedulerFactoryBean. It is the Scheduler bean(to be precise calling its start method invokes the aggregated QuartzScheduler.start method which fires the Trigger-s), provided by the SchedulerFactoryBean. As a matter of fact this Scheduler is stored(and looked-up) under the schedulerName(which if not explicitly set has the same default value for every configured SchedulerFactoryBean) in the SchedulerRepository singleton(SchedulerRepository.getInstance()). 
>   That's how unless you set a different schedulerName for your SchedulerFactoryBean-s, you will always get the same scheduler by each and every SchedulerFactoryBean-s

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?40945-Multiple-Quartz-SchedulerFactoryBean-instances

I know this refers to Spring Beans but i still think the same applies here.

Comment: Hi @ant, drobson thanks alot... Can you please tel me how to define or which method is used to set name for a scheduler in java not in XML.

Comment: I dont know how you name it without an xml properties file. I've tried looking for the JavaDocs but can't find anything.